# geth - How to unlock multiple accounts with multiple password files in command line

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a private blockchain with two accounts in my genesis.json file and tried to unlock both. I tried multiple methods and all failed. I tried

> geth --networkid 42 --datadir
>   "~/data/privateEthereum/client" --nodiscover --rpc --rpcport "8042"
>   --port "30303" --ipcpath "~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc" --maxpeers 3 --nat=any --rpccorsdomain "*" --unlock "0 1" --password "password0.txt password1.txt"

Solutions?

Answer (score 7):

At first, you should create a password.txt file of one per line ,and then run this command:

```
geth --datadir=~/data/privateEthereum/client --unlock "0,1" --password "password.txt" console
```

For the Ethereum account, there is more infomation here [Managing your accounts](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts)